# how to pass a class to be tested to an unit test class

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I have a class and I need to test it

```
class ToBeTested():
    def my_method():
        pass
```

I have designed some unittests in python.

```
import unittest
class MyFirstUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        # prepare some data
        # run a method
        # collect results

    def test_one_assumption_about_results(self):
      #self.assertEqual(...)

    def test_another_assumption_about_results(self):
      #self.assertEqual(...)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have designed this code looking at the examples.
Now I do not understand how to interface it the tesing class `MyFirstUnitTest` with the classe to be tested `ToBeTested`?

By inheritance?

```
  class MyFirstUnitTest(unittest.TestCase,ToBeTested):
       ######
```

By creating a object of class `ToBeTested` as static member of
   `MyFirstUnitTest` class definition?

```
class MyFirstUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):
    mytestobj=ToBeTested()
    def setUp(self):
```

By creating a object of class `ToBeTested` within each of the test
   cases of `MyFirstUnitTest` class definition?

```
 class MyFirstUnitTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
    ### 
    def test_one():
        mytestobj=ToBeTested()
    def test_two():
        mytestobj=ToBeTested()
```

please suggest alternatives and why you would prefer any of them

Comment: Could you please give a link to the examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a drawback to using inheritance and static member instead of creating a new object for every test: If tests change the state of the object, then the tests influence each other with their side effects. This gets even worse if the order of the test method calls are not guaranteed and changes (say, you rename a test and suddenly a different test case fails - these things have happened before!)

Additionally, having your test case inherit from the SUT (subject under test) means you only get to test one constructor.

I don't see any advantage to having the testcase inherit from the SUT, especially in python where there are no private members. If for some reason inheritance is necessary for the test (which sometimes IS the case), then having a seperate TestAdapter class that inherits and is instantiated by the test is the best practice.

There are other questions with answers which go more in depth:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366425/making-a-test-fixture-inherit-from-the-sut-class

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154144/how-to-define-implementation-details

Comment: clear disadvantage for static member. can you add an example of drawback for inheritance model?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo it's the same thing only your static variable is `this`. Also you only get to test one constructor of your class. I can't really think of an advantage of the inheritance model, especially in python where everyone can access everything (in other languages you could make a case that inheritance helps you test private methods, but imho it's not the test case that should inherit).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance of your class(es) in your setup if it will not have to be reinstantiated.
And if you have to create a new instance in every test then just create a new instance in every test.

Comment: any drawback of the inheritance based approach?

Comment: Perhaps you would want to test a function without/with having run another before. If you use an instance per test function you can make it clear when you want to run functions together or alone.